# ShapeNet not rendered with two-sided brdf

Tags: python, mesh, materials, objects, shaders

I am super new to Blender and was trying to render ShapeNet. I used this link as a reference: [ShapeNet Renderer](https://github.com/panmari/stanford-shapenet-renderer). The code works for the most part except some categories such as a car or a plane. I believe it is because the materials for these categories is not correctly imported. I get small black triangles, everything else renders fine. An example:

[image: example render]

Any ideas on how to fix this? So far I have swithced off Auto Smooth, enabled backface culling and made normals consistent. I am not sure what else I can do, and feel lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It either looks like Z-fighting (coplanar superimposed meshes) or your renderer doesn't support N-Gons. Try triangulating the mesh

Comment: Hey! So I checked the meshes which were not rendering well and they all seem to be triangulated. I think the issue might be z-fighting, but I am not sure how to get rid of it. I am already using the remove_doubles option in my script